# Counting X's and O's in a string in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I'm not sure why my code is not working, I think my logic is right?

Have the function ExOh(str) take the str parameter being passed and return the string true if there is an equal number of x's and o's, otherwise return the string false. Only these two letters will be entered in the string, no punctuation or numbers. For example: if str is "xooxxxxooxo" then the output should return false because there are 6 x's and 5 o's.

```
ExOh(str) 
i = 0 
length = str.length 
count_x = 0 
count_o = 0 

while i < length 
if str[i] == "x"
    count_x += 1 
elsif str[i] == "o" 
    count_o += 1 
end 
i+=1 
end 
    if (count_o == count_x)
        true 
    elsif (count_o != count_x)
    false 
end 
end
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem with your code is the function declaration. Use `def ExOh(str)` at the start. It may help if you indented also.

```
def ExOh(str)
  i = 0
  length = str.length
  count_x = 0
  count_o = 0

  while i < length
    if str[i] == "x"
        count_x += 1
    elsif str[i] == "o"
        count_o += 1
    end
    i+=1
  end

  if (count_o == count_x)
    true
  elsif (count_o != count_x)
    false
  end
end
```

By the way, a simpler solution using the standard library #count https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-count

```
def ExOh(str)
  str.count('x') == str.count('o')
end
```

Comment: You beat me too it. This simple solution using count is the best way

Comment: Omg thank you I can't believe I forgot the def in front, I was banging my head over why it didn't work!